# WinSCP clobbers permission & group on replace

Tags: permissions, winscp, ownership

Is there a way to tell winscp to keep the group and permission of my upload file? I am tired of modifying webpages/webapp binaries and needing to change the group to www-data so the server can read them.

If not what app might i use instead? I mostly use winscp for the easy of copy/pasting files onto my linux server and the ease of browsing the filesystem (can go between 2+ folders in a second, no typos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the gid of the folder and it should now keep the group to www-data provided the folder group is also www-data

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're having the problem because WinSCP removes existing files before uploading new ones - which should never happen *unless* you do not have the 'write' permissions on the old file, in which case deleting and replacing is the only way for WinSCP to upload your files.

When creating a new file on Linux, the creator's primary group will be the file's group<sup>1</sup>, and the permissions will be calculated<sup>2</sup> using (0666 & ~umask). The owner can modify permissions, but can only change the file's group into a group he himself belongs to.

In the case of a website, I usually set the `setgid` bit on the directories, so that all files I create inside become owned by that group:

```
sudo chown -R :www-data public_html/
find public_html/ -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
```

If the server's filesystem has ACLs enabled, you could also specify default permissions for the group:

```
setfacl -Rdm g::rX public_html
```

Or you could skip the "setgid" and "chgrp" steps, and just assign default permissions to the group you want:

```
setfacl -Rm g:www-data:rX public_html
setfacl -Rdm g:www-data-rX public_html
```

(The commands with `-d` set *default* permissions.)

---

1. Unless the directory has the *setgid* bit, which makes newly created files inherit the directory's group.
2. Can be influenced using default ACLs on the directory.

Comment: 'which should never happen unless you do not have the 'write' permissions on the old file' <-- Thats the thing, the directory is 777 and so are all the files. I do chmod -R 777 ./ constantly then when everything works i fix the bin folder permission

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure WinSCP not to transfer to a temporary file (which is then renamed to the target file name). Then WinSCP will directly write to the target file, and keep the permissions/ownership intact.

Go to the [*Prefereces > Transfer > Endurance > Enable Transfer to Temporary Filename*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_resume).